# How to notate repeat section for lead sheet

Tags: notation, musical-forms, repeats, lead-sheets

I'm having trouble writing a compact lead sheet for a song with this form:
A A B A B C B B

How to write it with repeat sign without make it too confusing? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using |: and  :| to indicate a repeat signs, I would write it as:

A |: A B :| C |: B :|

It is pretty straight forward and uses only 2 sets of repeats. No DC, DS repeat endings or coda. Assuming the sections are 8 bars each it would be 40 bars long.

Here is a slightly shorter but potentially more confusing way to do it:

[image]

Based on 8 bar sections this would only save 6 bars. I would go with the first version but I wanted to provide one other shorter option.